# Passing complex information in Angular directives

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using JQuery UI in an Angular application.  I noticed that I was repeating the same pattern for each directive:  Call the JQuery UI function with a single complex object for initialization.  Rather than write separate directives for each component, I have found it easier to use a stub directive.  This may not be a long term solution but it works for now.

Is there a better way to inject the attributes to make the markup more readable while still keeping the generic nature of the directive?  Specifically, can I avoid using a JSON string so that it reads more like a normal angular directive.

The existing line:

```
<button jquiw-control='{"control":"button","options":{"label":"Hello","icons": {"primary": "ui-icon-gear","secondary": "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"}}}' ng-click="jump()"></button>

<button jquiw-control="button" jquiw-button-label="Hello" jquiw-button-icons-primary= "ui-icon-gear" jquiw-button-icons-secondary="ui-icon-triangle-1-s" ng-click="jump()"></button>
```

Here is a plunk of a working example of my Generic ui directive. http://plnkr.co/edit/eRoOeq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you can put the hardcoded JSON in the controller like this

```
$scope.config = {
    "control": "button",
        "options": {
        "label": "Hello",
            "icons": {
            "primary": "ui-icon-gear",
            "secondary": "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        }
    }
};
```

and then change the template to

```
<button jquiw-control='{{config}}' ng-click="jump()"></button>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yY1Lc2?p=preview

Comment: I really wanted to keep this in markup.  I think I am just going to have to bite the bullet and do the directives by hand.  I ran into another problem in which multiple jquery ui components/plugins are placed on an element. <sigh>